# How to switch keyboard layout on right cmd press

Tags: macos, keyboard, bettertouchtool

I want to make a shortcut for keyboard **layout switching**. The problem is I want it to be one key and I want this key to be specific "**right cmd**". Previously I used PuntoSwitcher to switch layout by cmd press but it works for left and right cmd and this is not behaviour I expecting.

Also, I tried to use betterTouchTool, but i cannot make 1 key shortcut there.

Is there any way to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go! https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner

## disregard below, only there for history.

~Sadly I did a lot of research on the modifier keys for OS X a while ago, and you cannot differentiate left and right `cmd` modifiers.~ However the keybind normally for changing keyboard configuration is cmd-control-space for myself. Thats the normal configuration to select the next input source.

This is kind of like the annoying `fn` modifier that has no use but Functions 1-12. But that can be fixed with software.

Would have posted as comment, but I can't post commends yet.

edit: Oh, and shortcuts always require two key presses. A modifier and a primary. Otherwise things wouldn't operate quite normally if you understand what I mean. Such as allowing an [a-z] key to be launching an app.

Comment: The normal shortcut is option control space.   https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/type-language-mac-input-sources-mchlp1406/10.14/mac/10.14